# Changing a web page's skin using AJAX

Tags: ajax, themes

I've got a cookie set up to store the user's theme preference, etc., but I've never used AJAX before, so I could use a little help.

I found [this simple little AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp), which is enough to get me started, but I'm not sure if I'd be better off having the server send pretty much the entire web page all over again, with the updated theme, or -- if it is possible -- having the server send a script that would modify the page, keeping the content intact, but changing the div, etc. properties in order to achieve the new look.

Thoughts? Comments? "You're doing it wrong, moron"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If changing theme means only change the classes of your divs and the elemtes of the structure of your page you must do it simply changing the class="" atribute of the html elemts involved. Ej: You can change postions, and floats, colors etc etc.. This would appen only in client without asking to the server again the page (0% traffic from server, nice!)

But, if changing theme means to get other html structure and hierarchy complety different: You dont have other way that ask to the server the page again with the new html...

Conclusion: Think about all those things, if you can get other theme only changin css you can/must use jquery to change the css properties. But, if not, you need to load the new html from the server...

I hope this help you

pd: sorry for my englisgh grammar if its not correct at all!

Comment: Hello, Javier!  Thanks for your response, but this is one of my older questions.  I've found that your answer is very accurate... I learned those things the hard way... trial and error!  However, with StackOverflow's and CodeReview's help, I have gotten it to work pretty perfectly!  If you want to see the final product, it is available here ( http://www.solarcoordinates.com/testing3/index.html ), and the code for the latest revision is available here ( http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/639/theme-skin-swap-version-2-css-driven ).

Comment: You are welcome! Perhaps there is no perfect answer. It depends on the complex of the layout of each theme. One more tip to keep in mind: the more differences between themes in the html layout, more difficult fit the theme on each page. Centering the theme changes on the css wil be easier to change each page of the entire site...